# How to resolve the error "Result of call to environment is unused"?

Tags: swift, debugging, swiftui

```
let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext

// Create the SwiftUI view and set the context as the value for the managedObjectContext environment keyPath.
// Add `@Environment(\.managedObjectContext)` in the views that will need the context.
let loginView = LoginView().environmentObject(GlobalEnviroment())
loginView.environment(\.managedObjectContext, context)

// Use a UIHostingController as window root view controller.
if let windowScene = scene as? UIWindowScene {
    let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
    window.rootViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: loginView)
    self.window = window
    window.makeKeyAndVisible()
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`.environment` returns a modified version of the `View` that has the environment passed into it. You need to actually keep/use the result of that function.

The simplest way to do that is to just chain it to what you already have.

```
let loginView = LoginView()
   .environmentObject(GlobalEnviroment())
   .environment(\.managedObjectContext, context)

if let windowScene = scene as? UIWindowScene {
        let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
        window.rootViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: loginView)
        self.window = window
        window.makeKeyAndVisible()
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for rectifying my stupid error.

Comment: You can mark it as correct/accepted by clicking the green checkmark.